# Bad Request when url has japanese characters in it (Wordpress)

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Getting this message when trying to access url with japanese character in it (example => (http://www.example.com/部長)):

```
Bad Request

Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.

Additionally, a 403 Forbidden error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

Using WordPress 3.9.1. Admin side all in english.

In wp-config.php

```
define('WPLANG');
```

My .htaccess

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-phpcgi .php
<files load-styles.php>
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php
</files>

# BEGIN W3TC Browser Cache
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary
    </IfModule>
        AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css text/x-component application/x-javascript application/javascript text/javascript text/x-js text/html text/richtext image/svg+xml text/plain text/xsd text/xsl text/xml image/x-icon application/json
    <IfModule mod_mime.c>
        # DEFLATE by extension
        AddOutputFilter DEFLATE js css htm html xml
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
# END W3TC Browser Cache
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: No wonder the server didn't understand such request: http://www.example.com/部長

Comment: Where did you find this URL? Wordpress should convert the Unicode characters within URL to punycode.

Comment: Hi Igor.
From title of a post it goest to url, so I made a title "部長" just for a test, and I got that url. And I want urls with japanese characters like here http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%A8%E3%83%A1%E3%83%AA%E3%83%A4%E3%83%BC%E3%82%A8%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B3%E3%83%BB%E3%83%92%E3%83%A7%E3%83%BC%E3%83%89%E3%83%AB

Answer (score 0):

I just wrote to support & get reply from them ⬇

```
We do not support Japanese characters in the website name or URL. So, you cannot access it.
```